# Brainteaser with 6 random variables and combinations

Tags: random-variables

Six points are drawn subsequently from a uniform distribution. The first two points are marked blue, the second marked green and the last two red on the real line. What is the probability of having the 2 blue points, the 2 red points and the two green points adjacent? (i.e. the points have order RRGGBB or BBGGRR etc.)

My initial attempt was to try an integral like:

$$ 3 \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} \int_{z}^{1} \int_{r}^{1} \int_{q}^{1} dp dq dr dz dy dx $$

Where the limits if the integration are determined by the previously drawn colours. So if we say that the first colour X can be drawn anywhere between 0 and 1, the next colour must be drawn from the smaller distribution between X and 1, and the next colour after than between the second colour and 1 and so on.

This integral gives $ \frac{93}{720}$, which I don't think is correct.

Instead a much more intuitive way to approach the question is to just think of the combinations of ways in which the colours can be arranged. There are $6!$ arrangements, of which $3! * 2^{3}$ give the order we require, which gives a probability of $\frac{1}{15}$.

If the second way of approaching the problem is correct, there must be an analogue to solving the problem with integrals - can anybody see find this second method?

Comment: Your second approach is correct.  Your first integral (before multiplying by $3$) seems to be the probability that each of the six draws is a new record, and I think gives  $\frac1{720}=\frac1{6!}$

Comment: Oh, I can't forsee any integrals (and that too six integrals) in a combinatoric problem! Anyways, the first one is way much complicated and unnecessary. Go with the second one! It is the expected and elegant way. 

Answer (score 1):

The combinatorial way of thinking is ok, we first make a choice of an uncolored $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)\in I^6$, where $I=[0,1]$, then we put the colors on the components. But ok, the OP asks for a way to see this result by using integrals. Here is this way. (Done by computation, and done by seing it is the same way as the combinatorial way.)

---

Let $A$ be the set of all $x\in I^6$ so that the intervals

- between $x_1$ and $x_2$,
- between $x_3$ and $x_4$,
- between $x_5$ and $x_6$,

are disjoint. Let $1_A$ be its characteristic function, one on $A$, zero else.

The needed probability $P$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P 
&=
\iint_{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2}
dx_1\; dx_2
\iint_{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2}
dx_3\; dx_4
\iint_{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2}
1_A(x)\;
dx_5\; dx_6
\\
&=
2^3
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
dx_1\; dx_2
\iint_{\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2\\x_3<x_4}}
dx_3\; dx_4
\iint_{\substack{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2\\x_5<x_6}}
1_A(x)\;
dx_5\; dx_6
\\
&=
2^3
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
\iint_{
\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2
\\x_3<x_4
\\x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4\text{ or }x_3<x_4<x_1<x_2
}
}
dx_1\; dx_2
dx_3\; dx_4
\iint_{\substack{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2\\x_5<x_6}}
1_A(x)\;
dx_5\; dx_6
\\
&=
2^3\cdot 2
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
\iint_{
\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2
\\x_3<x_4
\\x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4
}
}
dx_1\; dx_2
dx_3\; dx_4
\iint_{\substack{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2\\x_5<x_6}}
1_A(x)\;
dx_5\; dx_6
\\
&=
2^3\cdot 2
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
\iint_{
\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2
\\x_3<x_4
\\x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4
}
}
dx_1\; dx_2\;
dx_3\; dx_4
\iint_{\substack{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2\\x_5<x_6
\\ \text{ and }
\\(\ x_5<x_6<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4\text{ or}
\\ x_1<x_2<x_5<x_6<x_3<x_4\text{ or}
\\ x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5<x_6\ )
}}
dx_5\; dx_6
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ and now we can compute or (simpler) further use the symmetry:}
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ The Computation:}
\\[3mm]
P
&=
2^3\cdot 2
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
\iint_{
\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2
\\x_3<x_4
\\x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4
}
}
dx_1\; dx_2\;
dx_3\; dx_4
\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot 
\frac 12
(\  (x_1-0)^2+(x_3-x_2)^2+(1-x_4)^2\ )
\\
&=
2^3
\iiint_{0<x_1<x_2<x_3<1}(x_1-0)^2(1-x_3)\;dx_1\; dx_2\;dx_3 
\\&\qquad
+2^3\iiint_{0<x_1<x_2<x_3<1}(x_3-x_2)^2(1-x_3)\;dx_1\; dx_2\;dx_3 
\\&\qquad\qquad
+2^3\iiint_{0<x_2<x_3<x_4<1}(1-x_4)^2 x_2\; dx_2\; dx_3\;dx_4 
\\
&=
2^3
\iint_{0<x_1<x_3<1}(x_1-0)^2(1-x_3)(x_3-x_1)\;dx_1\;dx_3 
\\&\qquad
+2^3\iint_{0<x_2<x_3<1}(x_3-x_2)^2(1-x_3)x_2\; dx_2\;dx_3 
\\&\qquad\qquad
+2^3\iint_{0<x_2<x_4<1}(1-x_4)^2 x_2(x_4-x_2)\; dx_2\;dx_4 
\\
&=2^3\left(\frac 1{360}+\frac 1{360}+\frac 1{360}\right)=\frac 1{15}\ .
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ Using the symmetry, from the point we started the computation:}
\\[3mm]
P&=
2^3\cdot 2
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
\iint_{
\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2
\\x_3<x_4
\\x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4
}
}
dx_1\; dx_2\;
dx_3\; dx_4
\iint_{\substack{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2\\x_5<x_6
\\ \text{ and }
\\(\ x_5<x_6<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4\text{ or}
\\ x_1<x_2<x_5<x_6<x_3<x_4\text{ or}
\\ x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5<x_6\ )
}}
dx_5\; dx_6
\\
&=
2^3\cdot 2\cdot 3
\iint_{\substack{(x_1,x_2)\in I^2\\x_1<x_2}}
\iint_{
\substack{(x_3,x_4)\in I^2
\\x_3<x_4
}
}
\iint_{\substack{(x_5,x_6)\in I^2\\x_5<x_6
\\ \text{ and }
\\ x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5<x_6
}}
dx_1\; dx_2\;
dx_3\; dx_4\;
dx_5\; dx_6
\\
&=2^3\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\frac 1{6!}=\frac 1{15}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$